# Given $\phi\colon G\rightarrow G'$ onto, does $\phi(G)=G'$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Working through Fraleigh's "Abstract Algebra ($7$th ed)" and came across lemma $8.15$ which says:

> Given groups $G$, $G'$ and an isomorphism $\phi\colon G\to G'$, then $\phi(G)$ (the image of G under $\phi$) is a subgroup of $G'$.

My question is, why doesn't $\phi(G)=G'$? Surely since the isomorphism is onto by definition, we must have the image of the domain is the whole codomain? Is it just a matter of saying that $\phi(G)$ is actually equal to $G'$, but since $G'$ is a trivial subgroup of itself it just makes it easier to state it like this?

Comment: I don't have my copy available, but are you sure that the book said $\phi$ is an isomorphism and not a homomorphism?

Comment: Yes you are totally right, an isomorphism is onto so the image is the total of $G'$. Sometimes in the literature it is meant that $G$ embeds isomorphically into $G'$, so then an injective homomorphism $\phi$ would be enough and then $G \cong \phi(G)$ of course.

Comment: I think the book must have defined isomorphism differently than usual notion of bijective homomorphism.

Comment: Actually looking back at it I seem to have misread the lemma, it defines $\phi$ as one-to-one homomorphism and for some reason I took one-to-one to mean bijection.

Comment: In my copy (seventh edition) this is not the statement. The statement I have is: "Let $G$ and $G'$ be groups and let $\phi:G \to G'$ be a one-to-one function such that $\phi (xy) = \phi (x) \phi (y)$ for all $x,y \in G$. Then $\phi [G]$ is a subgroup of $G'$ and $\phi$ provides an isomorphism of $G$ with $\phi[G]$"

Comment: $\phi(G)$ is a subgroup of $G'$, even when the group homomorphism $\phi$ is not bijective, injective or onto.

Comment: Aye, looking back at the textbook and actually reading it properly I've realised this is what it says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are completely right regarding your question stated in the title: if $\phi\colon G\to G'$ is onto (i.e. surjective) then by definition the image $\phi(G)$ equals all of the codomain, that is $\phi(G)=G'$.

Anyway, I have to agree with *André Armatowski*. In my copy Lemma $8.15$ also reads as

> **Lemma** $\textbf{8.15}$ Let $G$ and $G'$ be groups and let $\phi\colon G\to G'$ be a one-to-one function such that $\phi(xy)=\phi(x)\phi(y)$ for all $x,y\in G$. Then $\phi[G]$ is a subgroup of $G'$ and $\phi$ provides an isomorphism.

First off, the requirement that $\phi$ is one-to-one is unnecessary for the conclusion that $\phi[G]$ (I will adopt Fraleigh's notation) is a subgroup. To see this, consider a group homomorphism $\varphi\colon G\to H$ that is, a set-function $\varphi\colon G\to H$ such that $\varphi(xy)=\varphi(x)\varphi(y)~\forall x,y\in G$.

> **Claim.** The image $\varphi[G]$ of $G$ under $\varphi$ is a subgroup of $H$.

*Proof.* As one can show directly from $\varphi$ being a group homomorphism, we have that $\varphi(e_G)=e_H$ and that $\varphi(g^{-1})=\varphi(g)^{-1}$. Therefore $\varphi[G]$ is non-empty. Now, let $\tilde x,\tilde y\in\varphi[G]$ then there exist $x,y\in G$ such that $\varphi(x)=\tilde x$ and $\varphi(y)=\tilde y$, respectively. Thus
$$\tilde x\tilde y^{-1}=\varphi(x)\varphi(y)^{-1}=\varphi(x)\varphi(y^{-1})=\varphi(xy^{-1})\in\varphi[G]$$
By the [subgroup test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/One-Step_Subgroup_Test), we conclude that $\varphi[G]$ is a subgroup of $H$.$~~~\square$

Lemma $8.15$ evolves around how we can obtain a trivial isomorphism from an injective function $\phi$ by restricting the codomain to the image of $\phi$. By definition, $\phi$ is surjective on its image and as $\phi$ is injective by assumption we obtain an isomorphism, i.e. a bijective group homomorphism. That's it.

Comment: @m1820 If anything remains unclear, please let me know so that I can adjust my answer accordingly :)

Comment: @m1820 Anything I can add to make you consider accepting the answer (and consequently closing up this question thread)?